# Select which Right-Click menu items to display in IE

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net

I'd like to disable the 'Refresh' option in the right-click menu for internet explorer. Our application uses Javascript, ASP.Net and VB, but I'm sure it'll need to be done through Javascript. Any code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why? You can't, but I'd be interested to know why you think it's necessary. I do hope you're not trying to remove all browser navigation functions for some reason, as that's a sure sign of Doing It Wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can't selectively disable one menu item using javascript. But you can disable the entire context menu. Here is the simple code snippet.

```
 document.oncontextmenu = function() {
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: And praise be for browsers which you prevent webpages form doing this.